# How to blend text onto a texture in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add text to a can of beans. [The example code](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=texture#webgl_materials_texture_partialupdate) uses render.copyTextureToTexture to blend textures together.

However, when I try to use it doesn't do anything.

When I tried to display textTexture on the cylinder it was fully transparent. Is the texture made before text is rendered in the first canvas?

Or do I need to somehow wait until the image is loaded and only then use copyTextureToTexture to add the text?

```js
//import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';

const ctx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '2em Lucida Sans Unicode';
ctx.fillText('Text to be added', 0, 75, 500);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 4 / 3, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true
});
renderer.setSize(320, 240);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var img1 = "https://i.imgur.com/IIToHlc.png";

var texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(img1);

textTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(document.getElementById('textCanvas'));

const position = new THREE.Vector2();
position.x = 1;
position.y = 1;
renderer.copyTextureToTexture(position, textTexture, texture1);

const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, 12, 32);
const material = [
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: texture1
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x5f5f5f
  }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x5f5f7f
  })
]

const cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cylinder);

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
scene.add(light);

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xafafaf, 1);
directionalLight.position.z = 1;
directionalLight.position.x = -0.5;
directionalLight.position.y = 0.2;

scene.add(directionalLight);

camera.position.z = 15;
camera.position.y = 0;

var zRotation = -0.005;
var maxZRotation = 0.5;
cylinder.rotation.z = maxZRotation;

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  cylinder.rotation.y += -0.02;
  cylinder.rotation.z += zRotation;

  if (cylinder.rotation.z >= maxZRotation) {
    zRotation = -0.005;
  }
  if (cylinder.rotation.z <= -maxZRotation) {
    zRotation = 0.005;
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

canvas {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Floating can of BEANS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="textCanvas" width="500" height="150" style="height:150px; width:500px; position: absolute; top: 512px; "></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify a material to make it able to blend material's color with the text texture:

[image]

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import {
  OrbitControls
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 3, 8);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
//renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", event => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
})

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.25));

let c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.width = 256;
c.height = 128;
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "magenta";
ctx.font = "bold 36px Arial";
let text = "I love Three.js";
ctx.fillText(text, c.width * 0.5, c.height * 0.5);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeText(text, c.width * 0.5, c.height * 0.5);
let tex = new THREE.CanvasTexture(c);
tex.offset.y = 0.25;

let u = {
    time: {value: 0},
    textTex: {value: tex}
}


let g = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 2, 4.5, 36, 1, true);
g.rotateY(Math.PI);
let m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x7f7f64,
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/floors/FloorsCheckerboard_S_Diffuse.jpg", tex => {
    tex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    tex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    tex.repeat.set( 3, 1 );
  }),
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  onBeforeCompile: shader => {
    shader.uniforms.time = u.time;
    shader.uniforms.textTex = u.textTex;
    shader.fragmentShader = `
        uniform float time;
        uniform sampler2D textTex;
      ${shader.fragmentShader}
    `.replace(
        `#include <map_fragment>`,
      `#include <map_fragment>
      
        vec4 textCol = texture(textTex, (vUv * 2. - 0.5) + vec2(-2., sin(time) * 0.25));
        vec3 col = mix(diffuseColor.rgb, textCol.rgb, textCol.a);
        diffuseColor = vec4( col, opacity );
      `
    );
    //console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  }
});
m.defines = {"USE_UV" : ""};
let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(o);

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

  let time = clock.getElapsedTime();
  u.time.value = time;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Adding shaders seems a bit too complicated for me at this point. I ended up adding the image into a canvas, and drawing the text over it.

Comment: @Raukgorth Yeah, it's an option too :)

Comment: @Raukgorth Understand that `copyTextureToTexture` _replaces_ the pixels in `dstImage`.  Thus if your whole image is 0xff0000ff (opaque red), and you copy a texture that is all 0x0000ff80 (blue, 50% transparent), you will get back a texture that is all 0x0000ff80 (blue, 50% transparent).  You will not get an alpha-blended image (0xff0080ff, solid pink), which is, in effect, what you are looking for.  For that alpha blending, you have to compose that image in the canvas (like you did), in the shader (like @prisoner849 did), or through another method.

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849 for this. I've implemented for my own usecase: a text which is not moving on a uniformly colored surface (`color: 0xF7DD51, map: tex,` => no texture). My text is displayed, but text color is blended with the material.color when shader is not implemented (as explained in previous comments). But when I try to implement shader as described here, the surface color is not displayed anymore and text background is black. I've been trying things for 6 hours without succes. What do I need to change in my shader definition ?